# What render engine to use with the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to figure out which render engine to use for the VSE only..

I'm unsure that something changes but maybe... the cycles one can use the GPU instead of game and internal?

Comment: You can use either - it could depend on what you will be rendering. For simple single colour text objects either one could be used, if you are rendering a realistic object that needs to look like it is a real item in front of the camera,  then you may find cycles will give the desired result.

Comment: I'm rendering just 2D videos from an hardware camera, nothing 3D releated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a quite important difference when you render Video footage only:

Only with Blender Internal you have the option of using Anti-Aliasing.
[image: Anti-Aliasing Panel]

And there is a bit of a speed gain or loss depending on your settings there. But it makes a huge difference as soon as you activate a Scale function of at least one Strip. Cranking the samples per pixel up there didn't really affect my image quality nor speed, so you could leave it at 5, but switching it off completely results in a performance increase, but a visible image quality decrease on edges.

GPU Usage is only available in Cycles though. And depending whether you want to include rendered footage from a Scene as well and what effect  you want to achieve (basically more photorealism vs. speed) you need to select your Engine accordingly.

So in your case I'd suggest you'd use Blender Internal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either - it could depend on what you will be rendering. For simple single colour text objects either one could be used, if you are rendering a realistic object that needs to look like it is a real item in front of the camera, then you may find cycles will give the desired result.

The active render engine is only used to turn a 3D object into a 2D image, so if you aren't adding any 3D rendered element to your video then the active render engine doesn't matter, the VSE itself doesn't use the render engine when mixing the final video.

Comment: What about GPU use though?  There is no GPU option when BI is selected, but I'm pretty sure the VSE can use the GPU.

Comment: When displaying the vse preview you have the opengl preview option which could benefit from the gpu. Various effects strips may use the GPU through opengl but I don't know of any specific GPU support in the VSE yet. Pretty sure cycles is the only place to directly make use of the GPU.

Comment: That's interesting.  I'll have to test it again, but I'm pretty sure I've used my GPU (Quadro m4000) to render VSE output where all I used it for was to mix some audio and video.